# Fabricjs: When I apply and re-apply Image filters, Image quality went down

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, fabricjs

I have applied invert, grayscale and other filters in my image using fabricjs and the image quality is going to down and then. please see the code below and let me know if any issue with the code. I am using the image (img) as pattern to fill the rectangle.

```
var filters = ['brightness','grayscale', 'invert', 'sepia', 'sepia2','blur', 'sharpen'];

var applyFilter = function(index, filter) {
    img.filters[index] = filter;
    img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}

var applyFilterValue = function(index, prop, value) {
    if (img.filters[index]) {
    img.filters[index][prop] = value;
    img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    }
}

img.filters[0] = new filter.Brightness({'brightness': 0});

$('body').on('click', '#blackwhite', function() {
    applyFilter(1, this.checked && new filter.Grayscale());
});
$('body').on('click', '#invert', function() {
    applyFilter(2, this.checked && new filter.Grayscale());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and found something strange.

I was adding an image to the canvas using

> var img = new fabric.Image(ele,{});

When i apply filter to above image the quality of the image went down.

But when i add image to the canvas using

> fabric.Image.fromURL("PATH TO THE IMAGE");

now applying filter to the selected image works perfact.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time of applying filter to an image we push one by one filters on filters array at last one null value is present if you remove that null value your original image will be displayed..

Comment: This is not helpful. Your answer is not clear as to what array you're referring to.